# PHP and Protobuf FieldMasks for Google API

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-php-client

I found [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf?_ga=2.54632939.-1945545866.1576782661#google.protobuf.FieldMask) just fine, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to set up the FieldMasks in PHP to update a CloudSchedulerClient.

The command should be like this:
`$client->updateJob($job, $updateMask);` but no matter what I set the `$updateMask` variable to, my code keeps saying `Expect Google\Protobuf\FieldMask`. If for instance I wanted to update the description of a cron job to "test", `'description' => 'test'`, how should I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share some code, that would be helpful.

The error suggests that you are not providing the proper type. Your code should look something like this:

```php
use Google\Protobuf\FieldMask;

$updateMask = new FieldMask([
    'paths' => ['description']
]);

$client->updateJob($job, $updateMask);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, jdp, after some twaking I figured how to do the rest. In case anyone lands here and is making the same mistake, I was trying to load the job first, but this along with jdp's answer did it:

` $job = new Job(['name' => CloudSchedulerClient::jobName($projectId,$location,$name), 'description' => $description]);`